# Checking for TCP port availability in WiX

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I'm writing an WiX installer for my application. One step requires to install IIS on a given non standard port (e.g. 50000). If the port is available I should proceed and install and run IIS otherwise I should take the first port available, starting from 50000. Is it doable in WiX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable with writing your own custom action with C# code.

I suggest you to let the user to choose the port with appropriate UI and you will check if the port is occupied, this will let the user to know if need to make a firewall rule or other stuff regarding this port in order to make your application run without IT restrictions.

Comment: ok thanks, the problem is I need to pass the port number back to my wxs script, I'm setting the port using this wxs code: <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="50000" /> Basically I need to pass the result of my custom action back to the Port= value field in the wxs file. I was reading is not possible to retrieve back return values from a custom action, just a boolean OK/ERROR outcome

Comment: You can use the session object. string MyPort = session["MYPORT"]; 
session["MYPORT"] = "newPort";